# Manually running celery scheduled tasks within Django

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

In my Django settings file I have something that looks like this:

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'my_task': {
        'task': 'tasks.my_task',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=4, minute=0),
        'kwargs': {'interval': 'hour', 'features': [], 'max_samples': 200,
                   'training_days': 90, 'force_update': False},
        'options': {'queue': 'my_queue'},
    },
}
```

What I would like to do is to be able to manually have this task asynchronously start. One way I know of to do this is:

```
task = settings.CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE['my_task']
tasks.my_task.apply_async(kwargs=task['kwargs'], queue=task['options']['queue'])
```

while this works it is a bit clunky for my tastes and I am looking for a better way.

*Is there a way to find celery's interpretation of the scheduled tasks defined in `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE` and manually running them from there?*

The closest I have found so far is `inspect().registered_tasks()` from `celery.task.control` but that seems to be more about the workers than the scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 95% sure I'm missing an important aspect of this but I'll give it a shot.

If you want to run a specific task async but kick it off yourself, can you not just do `your_task.delay()`?

If you want to run all your scheduled tasks manually, just parse `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE` from `django.conf.settings`, importing each task and running `.delay()` on it.

*EDIT:* you seem to be doing something similar in your example. Are you able to say why you don't like this solution?